# How do I pass a value to 'LPVOID lpReserved in Windows DLL entry point

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I am using CreateRemoteThread to load my DLL in another applications, but my question is how I can pass for exemple a string to my dll and retrive it from lpReserved ? I heard something like that is possible.

Comment: See right at the end of this article, use VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory, then CreateRemoteThread and wait for the result: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions

Answer (score 1):

The remote process has a different virtual address space than the calling process, so indeed pointer values will be different. You would need to allocate memory specifically in the remote process, typically using [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex), which can allocate memory in a different process and return a pointer that's valid for that remote process only. You can pass this value via `lpParameter`.

I assume you mean `lpParameter`, and not `lpReserved`.

See also: [DLL Injection with CreateRemoteThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750112/dll-injection-with-createremotethread)